# Does set notation apply also for sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a very simple question with regards to the notation of sequences.
To illustrate the question, consider the following pseudo-code:

procedure **fun**(P):
// input  $P = \langle p_0,\ldots,p_{n-1}\rangle$
if $P == \langle \rangle$
  **return**;
for all $p_i \in P$
fun($\langle p_i,\ldots,p_{n-1}\rangle$);

That is, the variable $P$ denotes a sequence of elements, where order matters.

1. Now the question is, can I check for an empty sequence like in the if statement ($P == \langle \rangle$)? If this is correct, do you still prefer another notation, e.g., $P == \emptyset$?
2. Is the call fun($\langle p_i,\ldots,p_{n-1}\rangle$) correct? 
   or should I use something like e.g., fun($P \setminus \langle p_i \rangle$)? Is the latter correct at all, i.e., can I use the set notation with sequence, but instead of curly braces used angled braces, like $P \setminus \langle p_i \rangle$?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Well, then how do I express that statement using sequences, as $P$ for me is a sequence not a set? I.e., how do I express $P\setminus \{p_i\}$ for sequences.

Comment: $P\setminus \{p_i\} $ means "set-minus": the **set** $P$ without the subset $\{p_i\}$.  I don't think you mean to say that, even allowing for angled brackets instead of curly ones.  Unless otherwise noted, a set is not assumed to be ordered.   Take set $A = \{ 0, 1, 2, 3\} = \{2, 1, 3, 0\}$.  It sounds, perhaps, that you want a partially ordered set, but then you need to designate how to compare the $p_i's$

Comment: What is it you want to express with $P\setminus \langle p_i \rangle$?

Comment: With $P \setminus \langle p_i \rangle$ I want to express that I have extracted the element $p_i$ from $P$, and now $P$ has one element less (removed $p_i$). Since you're saying that my expression is incorrect, then how to correctly express it for sequences?

Comment: The backslash is customarily used in math to mean to identify a set, but also exclude any of its elements that share elements with the excluded set,  So $A\setminus B$ excludes all elements in $A\cap B$.

Comment: Let's just say the first alternative you mention in (2) will the better one.

Comment: I'm still interested to know the equivalent of $P \setminus \{p_i\}$ for sequences?

Comment: With your expressed intent, are you seeking to re-define P such that $P:=P\setminus \langle p_i\rangle$.  But then do you want to do something with the (extracted) $p_i$? Because once extracted from P, in a way that P is then defined without $p_i$,

Comment: A sequence does not qualify as a set; the specific entries in a sequence can repeat, indefinitely, and they are indexed from "first entry" to "last entry", or in the case of an infinite sequence, when there is no "last entry", then in place of a "next entry" after writing out a number of entries, we end with $\ldots$.

Comment: Please [see the Wikipedia entry for Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence). It more closely resembles/can be thought of, as ordered n-tuple in your case.  The most succinct and also correct notation for what you seem to be working with is $$P = (p_i)_{i=0}^{n-1}$$.

Comment: Ok then, how to I remove an entry from the sequence, such as $p_i$. As you can see it in the given pseudocode, I iterate over the sequence, and remove entries one by one, and the function **fun** is called again with the same sequence, but with one entry removed, i.e., $p_i$.

Comment: This is where someone with more programming experience than I(There are a good number here),  may be able to help you. Good luck!

Comment: I'm interested to just express it mathematically in the pseudocode. In programming I know how to do it.

Comment: @amWhy anyways thanks a lot for your help and efforts. I decided that I will just represent the elements as list, which is a structure that programmers well understand.

Comment: Great!  That's what I thought, all along, would work best.  (I know Java pretty well, but haven't learned the syntax of other languages.)

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat awkwardly, there is a lack of universally agreed notational conventions for sequences.  To circumvent this problem, I would recommend that you **express a sequence as a set.**

In particular, we can represent a sequence as a function, whose domain is a subset of the natural numbers.  Additionally, a function is a sets of ordered pairs $(x,y)$, where $x$ is the input and $y$ is the output. By expressing a list as a set, we can apply the relevant notation for sets and would allow the reader to work with more familiar notation.

In sum, to answer both of your questions, by recasting the sequence as a set $P$, you can then make mathematically correct statements of the form $P == \emptyset$ and $P \setminus \{p_{i}\}$.